# Max numbers of 10 devices limit via RunBulkEnrollmentOperationAsync with Azure IoT Device Provisioning Service

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub

Error below occurs when I tried to provison more 1000 devices using the code below:

> Exception: only allow 10 devices

```
       public async Task<List<IndividualEnrollment>> CreateBulkIndividualEnrollmentsAsync()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nCreating a new set of individualEnrollments...");
            List<IndividualEnrollment> individualEnrollments = new List<IndividualEnrollment>();
            foreach (var item in _registrationIds)
            {
 var symmetricKey = _symmetricKeyGenerator.GenerateSymmetricKey(activeDeviceToAdd.RegistrationId);
                var symmetricKeyAttestation = new SymmetricKeyAttestation(symmetricKey, symmetricKey);
                var individualEnrollment = new IndividualEnrollment(item .RegistrationId, symmetricKeyAttestation);

                individualEnrollments.Add(individualEnrollment);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("\nRunning the bulk operation to create the individualEnrollments...");

    //exception hits the line below:
                BulkEnrollmentOperationResult bulkEnrollmentOperationResult =
                    await _provisioningServiceClient.RunBulkEnrollmentOperationAsync(BulkOperationMode.Create, individualEnrollments).ConfigureAwait(false);
                Console.WriteLine("\nResult of the Create bulk enrollment.");
                Console.WriteLine(bulkEnrollmentOperationResult);

                return individualEnrollments;
            }
```

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-iot-samples-csharp/blob/master/provisioning/Samples/service/BulkOperationSample/BulkOperationSample.cs

**Update:**

My question is that is there a way or other solution to increase to more than 10 devices?

Answer (score 0):

The bulk operation is limited to maximum of 10 enrollments per request.

For details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iot-dps/runbulkindividualenrollmentoperation/runbulkindividualenrollmentoperation

You can batch the data on client side to 10 per request.

**Edit:** Currently there is no way to increase it. Increasing this limit has other side effects so better solution is to do client batching.